# Click a form button element on page load

Tags: javascript, html, forms, web

I am attempting to:

1. Click a button element on page load, and;
2. Make the form invisible

Currently the JS / HTML is:

```
<iframe src="https://api.leadconnectorhq.com/widget/form/FORMHERE" style="border:none;width:100%;" scrolling="no" id="FORMHERE"></iframe> <script src="https://api.leadconnectorhq.com/js/form_embed.js"></script>
```

I have tried `document.getElementById('watchButton').click` but I have no knowledge on where to put it

Or if I should be creatinga whole other JS / HTML element to perform the click

Comment: What form? The iframe? You can not access an iframe in a different domain.

Comment: There isn't a form element or a button in your code snippet. Please post that part of your code,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.